# Flutter how to reach parent widgets text form fields value?

Tags: android, flutter

i have a appbar with text-field for search.but when i route another page i just update the body of exited scaffold.doing this way i cannot reach to appbars text field value from called widget. how to do send value from appbar to child widget when input changed?

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("appTitle"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextField(),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              _onSelectItem(1);
            },
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                "Oyuncu Sorgula",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontFamily: "Montbold",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: _getstatefulwidget(_selectedDrawerIndex),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can use a callback, a service, or a state management solution like provider. There are a lot of ways to approach this, really.

Comment: Give [this](https://github.com/google/flutter_flux) a read

Comment: thanks i use state management.